# An extreme point of the ball of the space of compact operators

Tags: banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, operator-norms

It is very easy to see that the unit ball of $c_0$ has no extreme points. I was trying to spot any extreme points in the unit ball of the space of compact operators on a Hilbert space (a *non-commutative* version of $c_0$) but without success.

> Does the unit ball of $K(\ell_p)$ have any extreme points for some $p\in (1,\infty)$?

Comment: For a Hilbert space there are none for basically the same reason as for $c_0$.  Use e.g. the fact that a compact operator maps some orthonormal basis to an orthogonal sequence.

Comment: There is also a more general fact that the unit ball of any non-unital C*-algebra does not have any extreme points.

Answer (score 8):

For $p\neq 2$ there are plenty of extreme points in $K(\ell_p)$.

J. Hennefeld, Compact extremal operators, Il. J. Math. 21 (1977) 61-65.